# Making hidden element display itself and then move using transition

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, contains

How do I make fix this code so the two element first becomes no longer hidden and then moves however much right smoothly using the transition. It works when the element doesn't begin hidden, but when it is, it just jumps to the end spot. How do I make this work without taking out hidden and reducing the elements width to zero.? Thanks.

```js
var one = document.getElementById('one');
        var two = document.getElementById('two');
        
        function myFunct() {
            two.style.display = 'flex';
            two.style.right = '70%';
        }
```

```css
#one {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;      
}
#two {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  min-width: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 1.5s;
  -webkit-transition: 1.5s;
  -moz-transition: 1.5s;
  -ms-transition: 1.5s;
  background-color: green;
  right: 0px;
 }
```

```html
<div id = 'one' onclick = 'myFunct()'>
  <div id = 'two'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `opacity: 0` first instead of `display: none` and using `translateX` instead of `right` will be better.

I also recommend [AnimeJS](https://www.animejs.com) since it makes animations and transitions a lot easier if you are using a bunch of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try manipulating the [visibility](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp) property instead of display:

```js
function myFunct() {
    two.style.visibility = 'visible';
    two.style.right = '70%';
}
```

```css
#two {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: flex;
    ...
}
```